# Why is a linux shared library .so possibly larger in memory than on disk?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I'm starting to code more in linux and trying to get a better feel for the environment/APIs which are very different from windows. Anyhow, I'm dabbling with shared libraries .so (versus a windows .dll) and noticed that when a shared object is loaded into memory, it's surprisingly LARGER by 7752 bytes than it was on disk? I was expecting the image on disk to match the image in memory, or maybe there's a bug in my demo code below?

Example from [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7s74EnfM7) shows this output:

```
Program returned: 0
Program stdout
Loaded: linux-vdso.so.1
Loaded: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
---------------------MEMORY-------------------------
libc.so.6 size: 2037344 bytes
7fb5733e4000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   .ELF............
7fb5733e4010  03 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00 c0 41 02 00 00 00 00 00   ..>......A......
7fb5733e4020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 e7 1e 00 00 00 00 00   @...............
...
7fb5735d5630  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
7fb5735d5640  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
7fb5735d5650  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
---------------------DISK-------------------------
libc.so.6 size: 2029592 bytes
7fb5731f2010  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   .ELF............
7fb5731f2020  03 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00 c0 41 02 00 00 00 00 00   ..>......A......
7fb5731f2030  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 e7 1e 00 00 00 00 00   @...............
...
7fb5733e17f8  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c8 e2 1e 00 00 00 00 00   ................
7fb5733e1808  4b 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   K...............
7fb5733e1818  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
```

**Question**

I'm curious why the shared library size discrepancy between disk versus memory?

Comment: In addition to globals, as pointed out by Misha below, sections in memory are often page-aligned but use a smaller padding size on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a variant, it could use rather large .bss section (uninitialized static and global variables).

For example, function

```
void foo(char * dst, size_t len)
{
    static char table[4096];
    static int initialized;

    if (!initialized)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof table; i++)
            table[i] = rand();
        initialized = 0;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        dst[i] &= table[i % sizeof(table)];
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that a `static char table[4096];`  occupies minimal space in the ,bss section on disk, but when loaded into memory, it expands to 4096 bytes, making the memory image larger than on disk, is that a correct interpretation? Thanks.

Comment: @vengy Exactly. BSS section occupies minimal section on disk, origin address and length, just two numbers. At the start this memory set to zero. Static variables just lie in this area of memory (i.e. their addresses are inside BSS), they aren't loaded into memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is a linux shared library .so possibly larger in memory than on disk?

A shared object is basically a program that has several entry points instead of one.  As such, it has a .text segment, a .data segment, and a .bss segment, exactly equal as a program itself.  When the dynamic loader loads it, it copies the .text segment and .data (initialized data) from the file it comes from, but the .bss (uninitialized data) comes directly from a zero filled segment, which has no representation in the file the library is stored.

For this reason, a library with a large uninitialized global data segment (with a large .bss segment) can be larger, when loaded, than the original file it loads from.

This also makes a program's size to be normally larger than the file it is stored in.  Didn't you realize? :)

Comment: The GNU toolchain supports a way to compress individual ELF sections by renaming a section name from `.debug*` to `.zdebug*` by using `objcopy --compress-debug-sections ...` so that would be another reason why a disk image would be smaller than its memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks @vengy, but I'm talking about something general, not about the GNU toolchain.